Oriented Bounding Box (OBB) of two child OBBs
Given two oriented bounding boxes (OBBs) each defined by a center point $p$, half-dimensions $d$ and an orientation quaternion $q$, how could I determine a (semi-) optimal parent OBB encasing both child OBBs?
I'm trying to achieve this without iterating over each corner point of both child boxes. The resulting OBB does not have to be optimal (i.e. as tight-fitting around the child boxes as possible), but reasonably tight for most scenarios.
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dinesh-Manocha/publication/2807460_Collision_Queries_using_Oriented_Bounding_Boxes/links/56cb392008ae5488f0daea80/Collision-Queries-using-Oriented-Bounding-Boxes.pdf
The linked dissertation mentions on page 40, section 3.1.2. that the OBB of two child OBBs can be created in $O(1)$, however it is not elaborated on as far as I can tell.

I think you didn't understand the context of the $O(1)$ comment. There are $k$ polygons, which you can work on pairwise to construct a binary tree of successive bounding boxes. Give two trees over a total of $k$ polygons, you can get a bounding box either by examining each of the $k$ polygons (this is $O(k)$), or by just using total boxes of the two trees (this is independent of $k$, and hence $O(1)$). Your examine-each-corner method would still be $O(1)$ in this context if the two input boxes are the total boxes of two trees.

I think the only way you're going to avoid examining vertices is something like the following: the radius of a sphere bounding each OBB is $d\sqrt[3]2$. Now construct the sphere bounding these two spheres. Now construct the box bounding this total sphere (with an arbitrary orientation).
